# What is an isomorphism?

Tags: soft-question, definition

I'm familiar with the concepts of *group isomorphism*, *ring isomorphism*, and *graph isomorphism*, but it's never been presented to me what an isomorphism is in general: given any X, what is an *X isomorphism*?

Informally, I understand isomorphism as "preservation of structure", where "preservation" is domain specific. Is there a formal definition?

Comment: I think you may need some knowledge about **Category Theory** and you will find #http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory#.

Comment: @Ran For questions like these, I think it might be a good idea to share a bit about your mathematical background, so that people can give a response that better suits your needs. Things like what kind of math courses you have taken in the past, what your interests are, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment suggests, looking up the word "morphism" in the context of "Categories" and Objects will give you a more rigorous and general idea about isomorphisms. But I always like to think of isomorphism as something that allows you to make copies of a given "object", be it rings or groups, or Topological spaces or manifolds,etc.

Conveniently you can also look at it as a transformation that allows you to preserve the algebraic / geometric / topological structure or atleast the most basic and desired properties pertaining to these.

Edit: The word "copies" might be very misleading actually. Its more prevalent in the context of "Product spaces" than here. But I could not find a better word.Actually I think it might be quite wrong to say copies. Instead I would go along with saying that it allows you to collect spaces which though not essentially copies of the original space still basically carry the same "bloodline" if you will. I realise that this is not a technically sound answer, but was trying to see how best I could put this without resorting too many technical terms.I apologise if this isn't what you need

Comment: Indeed, looking up 'morphism' was helpful. I see now that it would be more accurate to refer to *group isomorphism* as *$\textbf{Grp}$ isomorphism*, since whether or not two things are isomorphic depends on the category.

Comment: Yes the category matters. It just so happens that we read about specific categories and morphisms without every having heard about General Category theory,as in my case. But I think thats not a bad thing anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have two structures $A$ and $B$, and suppose you call a function $f:A\to B$ "good" if it satisfies certain properties (for $A,B$ topological spaces, we might want $f$ continuous, for $A,B$ vector spaces we might $f$ to be a linear transformation, &c). Suppose that $f$ is invertible, and $f^{-1}$ is also "good". Then we say $f$ is an isomorphism. In the setting say of vector spaces, rings or groups, whenever $f$ is invertible, it is automatically "good" too, so sometimes people define an isomorphism to be an "invertible homomorphism" say when talking about groups or rings. However, one can give counterexamples when $A,B$ are topological spaces: there exists invertible continuous $f:A\to B$ such that $f^{-1}:B\to A$ is discontinuous.